# Can I get a Dockerfile reviewed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions, specific-language

I'm in the process of (hopefully) finishing up my first Dockerfile, and I was wondering if I'd be able to post it here, and see if I'm using Docker right, if the commands (it's based on Ubuntu so they're bash) could be improved etc.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see why not. We allow questions on languages like [makefile](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/makefile) and [bash](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash), and Dockerfiles wouldn't be that different.

Be sure to include contextual information about what the container is intended to be used for, and how it might fit with other containers you might have.

Comment: Will do, thanks!